# PHP Copy not copying

Tags: php

I have been searching for an answer everywhere all morning, and I can't seem to find one. Even on here, so please don't mark as a duplicate.
Basically, I am using php to make a dir and then copy a file to it:

```
mkdir('servers/'.$name.'/');
sleep(2);
copy("dummy/text.txt", "servers/".$name."/text.txt");
```

But that doesn't work. I even tried: `copy("dummy/text.txt", "servers/$name/text.txt");` and `copy('dummy/text.txt', 'servers/'.$name.'/text.txt');`

Also, (for testing) I chmod the directory (whole thing, including sub folders) 0777 and chown www-data:www-data still not working.

Please help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If not is error reporting enabled?

Comment: Also your creating a directory in the present dir with `$name` but then trying to copy to `servers/$name` is that dir present there?

Comment: is that working `copy("dummy/text.txt", $name."/text.txt");` ?

Comment: Sorry! I was a little frustrated so I typed fast. I made the directory using: mkdir('servers/'.$name.'/');

Comment: And the directory exists

Comment: Also, (for testing) I chmod the directory (whole thing, including sub folders) 0777 and chown www-data:www-data still not working.

Comment: Sorry, but "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful as an issue report!  You should check for warnings and errors emitted by your code.  also, functions like mkdir and copy can fail and will return false if they do so.  You're not bothering to check for success, which is not good practice.

Comment: I don't know how to get the log of the copy function. Safe mode is off, mkdir works, copy doesn't. When I issue copy, it doesn't copy the file to the directory I previously told it to make.

Answer (score 0):

you create the dir not where you want to copy the file afterwards.

```
mkdir("servers/".$name);
```

Also i recommend that before you ceate the folder, you check if it exists already:

```
if(!is_dir("servers/".$name)){
  mkdir("servers/".$name);
}
```

Comment: Sorry! I was a little frustrated so I typed fast. I made the directory using: mkdir('servers/'.$name.'/');

Comment: and the directory exists.

Comment: Also, (for testing) I chmod the directory (whole thing, including sub folders) 0777 and chown www-data:www-data still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Found it out! Before I created the script I made a typo when I made the directory myself. I did (on cli): sudo mkdir dumm**m**y (3 "m" s) Then I made the scripts the correct spelling. Ugh, I have been wasting a full 3 and a half hours on that :P